# TypeError: Cannot read property 'imports' of undefined (react-quill)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, react-quill

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'imports' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/abc/finaltest/node_modules/quill-image-resize-module/image-resize.min.js:1
```

I installed quill-image-resize using:

```
npm i --save quill-image-resize-module
```

Since I'm using react and thus do not have a tsconfig file, I'm unable to follow solutions available on the internet.

My code:

```
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
import Quill from 'quill';
import { ImageResize } from 'quill-image-resize-module'; 
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

modules = {
        
        toolbar: {
            container:this.toolbarOptions,
            
        },
        ImageResize: {
            modules: [ 'Resize', 'DisplaySize', 'Toolbar' ]
        }        
        
}
```

this is what I get when I hover on the import statement

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'quill-image-resize-module'. 'c:/Users/abc/final blog/finaltest/node_modules/quill-image-resize-module/image-resize.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I tried using the `require` statement, but the error remains the same.

These are my dependencies:

```
"quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
"quill-image-resize-module-react": "^3.0.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-quill": "^1.3.5",
```

I tried the same with quill-image-resize-module-react, but I couldnt solve the error. My reactquill editor worked before this. I'm not using webpack so I dont even have webpack.config.js to try and solve the issue. I havent done any changes to the original files in node_modules/quill-image-resize-module.

This is the first time I'm trying react and thus would appreciate some help. I'm more than certain it is something under my nose that I'm not able to see. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Same problem here, I use vue  but don't have a webpack file so am not able to follow the internet solutions. Although some suggested to downgrade the image-resize from ^3 to ^1.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll try and see if its any better. @AadeshDhakal

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the fixed version here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-image-resize-module--fix-imports-error

And it will solve the problem.